# How can i creat a generic method for this calling statement using C#

Tags: c#

Is there any way of creating a generic method for this calling statement using C#

```
string a = Program.GenericTester(walter => walter.GetDetails(), dog);//calling statement
Console.WriteLine("Result A: {0}", a);
int b = Program.GenericTester(snowball => snowball.Age, cat);
Console.WriteLine("Result B: {0}", b);
```

Comment: Am total lost because is for the first time using C# i just got this as Assessment

Comment: Well for starters you need to show what GenericTester is as well as GetDetails.

Comment: Which parts should be generic and what are the constraints?

Comment: @sr28 GenericTester here is a name of method that i requested a help about and for GetDetails is a class as well as dog.

Comment: @grek40 the thing is i just got this calling statement so they said i must create a generic method for this

Comment: You are very unspecific. `GetDetails` is most certainly not a class but a method. `dog` would be a variable, holding an instance of a class. If you want meaningful generics, lets talk about types, not about variables and methods. I deduct from deep looks into my crystal ball, that `cat` and `dog` have different types, the type of `walter` equals the type of `dog`, the type of `snowball` equals the type of `cat` and the `GenericTester` return type equals the return type of the first parameter input function. Did I hit something?

Comment: @grek40 you are 110% right.how about i send you the assessment then you can get what i mean because i can clearly see i don't explain in a proper way.So you can help me to create the generic method required

Answer (score 0):

As commented, I assume the following composition: `cat` and `dog` have different types, the type of `walter` equals the type of `dog`, the type of `snowball` equals the type of `cat` and the `GenericTester` return type equals the return type of the first parameter input function.

A possible generic method signature would be

```
public static TResult GenericTester<TSource, TResult>(Func<TSource, TResult> func, TSource item)
{
    // ...
    return func(item);
}
```

Or, if `dog` and `cat` have a common base class type `Animal` and only instances of that type would be allowed, a type restricton could be enforced on the generic parameters with the `where` clause.

```
public static TResult GenericTester<TSource, TResult>(Func<TSource, TResult> func, TSource item)
    where TSource : Animal
{
    // ...
    return func(item);
}
```

Comment: I thanks you for enlighten  me i'll try it and come back to you,may almighty god give you more in your life

Comment: how can i change this methods into generic ones                                             public static void ShowSomeHumanInformation(Human human)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name:" + human.Name + " Age: " + human.Age);
        }

        public static void ShowSomeDogInformation(Dog dog)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name:" + dog.Name + " Age: " + dog.Age);
        }

        public static void ShowSomeCatInformation(Cat cat)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name:" + cat.Name + " Age: " + cat.Age);
        }

Comment: @Derick please don't ask new questions in comments. Generally, if it is an assignment you should first try to solve it yourself. If you have a specific problem, ask a new question and provide as much information as you have (the assignment) as well as your solution attempts / thoughts. Try to focus questions on things that you actually need to *understand the topic* rather than *getting the solution*. (edit: maybe I misread assessment for assignment^^)

Comment: oh i understand i thanks once again and as for generic method i did them.Is assessment and i worked on it and manage to complete other session but others i don't understand them just like the ones for generic method because is for the first time coming across this.